# Kafka jdbc sink connector with json schema not working

Tags: json, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Using the latest kafka and confluent jdbc sink connectors. Sending a really simple Json message:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "struct",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "int",
                "optional": false,
                "field": "id"
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "optional": true,
                "field": "msg"
            }
        ],
        "optional": false,
        "name": "msgschema"
    },
    "payload": {
        "id": 222,
        "msg": "hi"
    }
}
```

But getting error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
```

Jsonlint says the Json is valid. I have kept json `schemas.enable=true` in kafka configuration. Any pointers?

Comment: Can you post your connector and Connect worker config please

Comment: I am starting kafka connect using the command: `./bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/sink-mysql.properties`

Comment: connect-standalone.properties:        
`bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets 
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000`

Comment: sink-mysql.properties: `name=test-sink-mysql-jdbc
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=2
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
connection.user=testuser
connection.password=testuser
pk.mode=record_value
pk.fields=id
insert.mode=upsert
auto.create=true
auto.evolve=false
topics=mynewtopic
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/mysql-sink.offsets`

Comment: I am not using schema registry or avro. I have added Confluent jdbc connector jar and mysql jdbc jar in the classpath

Comment: I am using kafka console producer to send messages to the topic from which kafka sink jdbc connector reads: `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic mynewtopic`

Comment: And i am deleting the 'mynewtopic' topic and re-creating it before every attempt to run this, so that previous messages with incorrect schema are not affecting the test results.

Comment: @prabhas I followed the exact steps to push data from kafka topic to postgresql using your sink properties and standalone properties file (in your case it is mysql), but I am getting some error. I have the same issue as mentioned in this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158092/push-data-from-kafka-topic-to-postgresql-in-json" kindly have a look at it and help me through. The data we are trying to send is JSON data similar to your message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell Connect that your schema *is* embedded in the JSON you're using.

You have:

```
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

But need also:

```
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

Comment: made the above changes (value.converter.schemas.enable=false) to the sink properties file, but same error. Then instead, made the same changes to the standalone properties file - still same error. Then in standalone properties file also set key.converter.schemas.enable=false. Now above error is not seen, but instead, I'm seeing the following error: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: No fields found using key and value schemas for table: mynewtopic ( I am still passing the same JSON string as message, to kafka console producer)

Comment: Finally this is what worked: I had to set `key.converter.schemas.enable=false` AND `value.converter.schemas.enable=true` . I had to make these changes in standalone.properties - I am still not able to override these settings in the sink.properties, but that is a separate concern. Thanks everyone for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: If your key has no schema, then yes `key.converter.schemas.enable=false` makes sense. Please remember to mark an answer as correct to help others find it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the JDBC sink, your streamed messages must have a schema. This can be achieved either by using Avro with Schema Registry, or by using JSON with schemas. You might need to delete the topic, re-run sink and then start source side once again if `schemas.enable=true` has been configured after initially running the source properties file.

**Example:**

`sink.properties` file

```
name=sink-mysql
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test-mysql-jdbc-foobar
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/demo?user=user1&password=user1pass
auto.create=true
```

and an example worker configuration file `connect-avro-standalone.properties`:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

# Local storage file for offset data
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets

plugin.path=share/java
```

and execute

```
./bin/connect-standalone etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink.properties
```

Comment: I am using pretty much the same configuration that you have suggested here (added in comments above), but still getting the exception. As already mentioned, I am not using schema registry or avro for now.

Comment: @prabhas Try to include `--property print.key=true` to your console consumer command. If it is printing out `null` keys, then this is the problem as JSON cannot decode null keys.

Comment: ok, thanks, that may be a problem. I am sending a json string to console-producer and expecting kafka jdbc connect to load it into a database table. But now I see that the Json itself does not specify which is the key - I have two fields id and msg. So apparently, I should specify the key in the inline json schema, for any chance for it to work. How do I specify the key in the inline schema?

Comment: `/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh \
  --broker-list localhost:9092 \
  --topic my-topic \
  --property "parse.key=true" \
  --property "key.separator=:"
"thsisIsKey1":JSON`

Note that in this example, the key is not in JSON format. If this is the case then in the worker configuration file you need to set `key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`

Answer (score 0):

I had recently came across same issue and it took multiple retries before i figure it out what was missing:

Following settings worked for me:

```
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

Also, make sure the table exists before in the database and connector should not try attempt creating one. Set
auto.create=false